# holden jackaroo won't kick over until the third attempt

Tags: starting, ignition, starter, holden

I've just bought a holden jackaroo and the last 3 days in the morning I have tried to start it but it doesn't even try to kick over but normally on the third try it starts like there is nothing wrong, what could it be? its a manual 1998 model, fuel injected, the dash lights come on as normal aswell

Comment: Does it click or do anything at all on the first two tries other than turn the dash lights on?

Comment: No nothing totally silent,  no sounds whatsoever

Comment: You could possibly have a starter problem. If the solenoid of the starter is going bad it more than likely wouldn't make any noise as you tried to start the car since nothing is actually engaging. The lights and everything else would work perfectly fine though since it's not a battery issue. Without the starter making any noise as you try the first two times, it also rules out a stuck starter. With the solenoid going out, the starter is just simply not even engaging.

Comment: It could also be in the ignition switch itself, but I'm scared of electrical gremlins so I don't know how to test it. PS I love the name. This was sold as an Izuzu Trooper in the states, which is so much less fun to say.

Comment: If it was the starter playing up what would it sound like? Maybe I just didn't hear it and if its the solenoid any idea what it would cost me to get it fixed?

Comment: If the starter itself is the problem and not the solenoid, you'll usually be able to hear a click as the solenoid tries to engage the starter but the starter doesn't actually move. A starter for this vehicle can be found for around $40-$50. If the solenoid is bad, you'll more than likely just replace the whole starter regardless. The removal of these starters can be kind of tricky since the exhaust pipe can sit right in the way. Here's a useful link if you want to try it yourself http://www.automotiveforums.com/t695072-replace_starter_without_removing_exhaust.html

Comment: Also, if you find a starter on your own and ask a local repair shop what their rates are, I wouldn't think this job would take much more than 2 hours to complete for an able mechanic.